# How to add a specific class for all posts from a certain category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I instaled a theme and i used a template from that theme. The template is not created by me. I don't have acces to the template code. I use a builder for building elements. I created a grid of posts from a category, but the builder doesn't add a specific class for all posts from that category. So, i want to add with a hook,  a class for all posts from the site from a specific category  (only for them). How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom class like that:

```php
<?php 
$custom_classes = array(
        'longform-article',
        'featured-story',
        'interactive',
    );
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $custom_classes ); ?>>
```

So if you want for categories:

```php
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array($category) ); ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

functions.php

```
function filter_post_class( $classes, $class, $post_id ) {
    $cat_slug = get_category_by_slug('your-category-slug'); // change your category slug here
    $cat_slug = isset($cat_slug->slug)?$cat_slug->slug:null;

    $cat_curr = get_the_category($post_id);
    $cat_curr = isset($cat_curr[0]->slug)?$cat_curr[0]->slug:null;

    if($cat_slug == $cat_curr){
        $classes[] = 'your-class-name'; // change your post class here
    }
    return $classes; 
}; 
add_filter( 'post_class', 'filter_post_class', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Make sure your looping content has "post_class();" called.
i.e. <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>...</article>